# SQL function: If Statement dosen't return specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

When I `INSERT` a User who is already in the Database, then the `RETURN "Error_UsernameExist"` should trigger but instead I get following Error message from the `function`: *Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'testUser' for key 'Username_UNIQUE'*

following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `registration`(usernameP TEXT, passwordP TEXT, saltP BLOB) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT `Username` FROM `DEV`.`RUser` WHERE `Username` = usernameP) = 1)  THEN
        RETURN "Error_UsernameExist";
    END IF;
    
    INSERT INTO `DEV`.`RUser` (`Username`, `Password`, `Salt`) VALUES (usernameP, passwordP, saltP);
    RETURN "OK";
END
```

Comment: Why do you expect your `SELECT` query to return `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` (SELECT `Username` FROM `DEV`.`RUser` WHERE `Username` = usernameP) `` evaluates to the actual Username being returned. Assuming the Username does not equal `1`, your IF statement is not true. Change your IF to
`` IF ((SELECT COUNT(`Username`) FROM `DEV`.`RUser` WHERE `Username` = usernameP) = 1) `` to check the number of users with that user name. You could also use IF EXISTS instead.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT `Username` FROM `DEV`.`RUser` WHERE `Username` = usernameP)
```